# How To Open The Last Opened Activity After Pause The Application

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to to add an Splash Activity to my application
this splash activity open when the program start for first time

but when the app work and skip the splash activity to main activity
and user hold on and go to the home screen

after that the user will return to the app ,,

the problem is here
so the application reopen the splash activity again

i don't want the app to open the splash activity every time the application resume activity
i need to direct open the main activity ...

I tried this code but it doesn't work with me

In Splash Activity ...

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        Class<?> activityClass;

        try
        {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
            activityClass = Class.forName(prefs.getString("lastActivity", MainActivity.class.getName()));
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
        {
            activityClass = MainActivity.class;
        }

        startActivity(new Intent(this, activityClass));
        
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        );
    }


}
```

and in the Main Activity i use this code

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        
    }
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("lastActivity", getClass().getName());
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Application class to save a global flag:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static boolean sFirstRun = false;

    public static boolean fetchFirstRun() {
        boolean old = sFirstRun;
        sFirstRun = false;
        return old;
    }

    //--called when app process is created--
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        sFirstRun = true;
    }
}
```

And in manifest.xml add : `<application  android:name=".App"`

now, `App.fetchFirstRun()` is true only when App process is created from scratch. As long as app is running subsequent calls will return false.

Comment: ,, thank you

do you mean I should use `App.fetchFirstRun()` on `Create` Method for SplashActivity ?

Comment: @lo2i yep, if its false, splash activity starts Main activity. else, it shows its fancy splash.

Comment: Thanks You So Much ,,, It Works Fine For Me

Does It Work Also For Applications have more than two Activities ?

Comment: @lo2i Yep, One Application class instance per app, any number of activities can call this static method.

Comment: Thank dude , i wanna to know how the mechanism of this operation will be ,, because assume that i have an application has 4 activities one for splash and three other for something else , now lets say the user navigate to the third activity and he press the home button and relaunch the app again when i use the method you put it return only two cases ,, how can i improve the code to do that .